# Setting up two locations on the same network

Tags: networking

I'm working on a project that involves setting up two buildings to be on the same network.  To give a background, there's building A which is the current building.  Recently, a new building has been added right next to it and there is a fiber connection between them (not currently plugged into anything, but tested and working).  Building A uses Charter uplink and has 192.168.0.0/24 while Building B is on an XO uplink and has 192.168.1.0/24. Both of the uplinks go through a SonicWall firewall at each building.

The challenge right now is to have the two buildings talk to each other, so that phones from building B can connect to the phone server at the building A and computers can communicate between the two buildings.  Also, in doing this, the XO uplink would be used as primary uplink for both buildings and Charter would be setup as a backup uplink (in case XO goes down).

What would be the best way to connect or maybe merge these two networks?  One of the ideas we have been throwing around is to just expand the 192.168.0.0 to a /22 so that it includes 192.168.1.0 network. I assume with this we would just need to change the subnet masks on devices and they should be good to go?

The second option that we have considered is to create static routes on both SonicWalls, but I am not sure if this would be the optimal setup.

Any advice or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: `One of the ideas we have been throwing around is to just expand the 192.168.0.0 to a /22 so that it includes 192.168.1.0 network` - Without spending any time thinking about this, this sounds like the least involved and least complex plan. You can change the subnet mask to a /23 to achieve this. A /23 would encompass 192.168.0.0-192.168.1.255. A /22 would encompass 192.168.0.0-192.168.3.255.

Answer (score 1):

From the information provided it seems unlikely that there is a third option. If you have two networks with a connection in-between and a corresponding device on each end that can do routing and/or bridging, you can either bridge them and extend the network to /23 (let's call it method A) or route them with static routing (B).
Of course there are pros and cons for each so I'll try to list them as well as I can:

- If static addressing is used, B is more preferable because you won't have to reconfigure all devices on the network. Dynamic addressing (DHCP) would not tip the scales towards A or B.
- In case the phones and perhaps some other devices have some strange requirements about the connection protocols used or does not have an option to configure a default gateway, it might be required to bridge the two networks (A).
- I don't know much about SonicWall and it's features, but generally with routing (B) you have more control on the traffic between the networks. If there are requirements connected to this, it might influence your decision.
- If each building has it's own uplink and there is a need for failover, it is much easier accomplished with B.
- A is slightly more "Plug and play" and therefore easier to implement, however B is more complex and requires some administrative effort. It might depend on how well you are acquinted with network configurations.

I personally would choose B over A any day, but I don't know your situation well enough to strongly recommend one or the other.

Comment: Actually, there will be only one uplink for the two buildings.  The 2nd uplink will be used as stand-by/backup in case first one goes down.  We tested using a /22 at building B yesterday and everything there seems to be working fine.  So at this point, we might just connect the fiber cable from building B (where the uplink will be) to the switch at building A and remove the SonicWall at building A.  That way they will both be on a /22.  Then later at some point use this spare SonicWall to set up HA at building B.

Comment: @sonicc Sounds good. But is there no option to leave an uplink at A as well? That could provide better redundancy and provide a possible contingency in case something happens with the connection between buildings.

Comment: that's what i actually ended up doing.